# jQuery Animate height on hover toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok i must be missing something stupid here but i am lost to why this wont work

```
    $('#fleet').hover(function(){
        var fleet = '2';
        $("#fleetHover").show();
        $("#fleet").animate({ "height": '+=' + (fleet * 30) + 'px' }, "slow");
    }, function(){
        $("#fleetHover").hide();
          $("#fleet").animate({ "height": '-=' + (fleet * 30) + 'px' }, "slow");
    });
```

When i hover the element it expands the height that i need. But when i mouse out it doesnt go back.

But if i do this with the height as a value and not a variable it works.

```
    $('#fleet').hover(function(){
        var fleet = '2';
        $("#fleetHover").show();
        $("#fleet").animate({ "height": '+=' + (fleet * 30) + 'px' }, "slow");
    }, function(){
        $("#fleetHover").hide();
          $("#fleet").animate({ "height": "-=60px" }, "slow");
    });
```

What am i missing here? I am slowly learning the JS/jQuery stuff can a variable not be used more than once?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `fleet` variable is defined inside of and scoped to the first anonymous function. It isn't accessible to the second anonymous function. One solution would be to define the variable outside of both functions:

```
var fleet = '2';
$('#fleet').hover(function(){        
    $("#fleetHover").show();
    $("#fleet").animate({ "height": '+=' + (fleet * 30) + 'px' }, "slow");
}, function(){
    $("#fleetHover").hide();
    $("#fleet").animate({ "height": '-=' + (fleet * 30) + 'px' }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Uggghhhh i am an idiot... the little jQuery stuff i do know that is one of them thanks for pointing out the obvious thing i was over looking works great now!

Comment: I would suggest making that into a function or that variable will be usable through out the script file. Refer to edit I made.

Answer (score 1):

**I will remove this answer if you don't want this option.**

Just use CSS3 animation with CSS hover states.

```
.grow {
  height: 140px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
}

.grow:hover {
  height: 200px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/dg7pH/)

Comment: Trust me i would love to use CSS for this, but i need a variable passed to me for the height from a Java application and i wouldnt know where to start with taking a Java object and putting it into the CSS

Comment: Ahh I understand! Well I am glad to hear you found a answer and best of luck mate, if you want me to remove my answer then feel free to let me know.

Comment: Doesnt matter to me, i love that you were thinking outside the box. CSS is where i go before JS :)

Comment: Yeah I am a CSS junkie and love what it is offering now. If only IE would just give up already, then us developers would be set!